# Parsing JSON with data with varing fields

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to polulate a html table using the JSON reponse. I have parsed and use angluar ng-repeat to fill the table. But now I noticed that the JSON reponse type may vary based on the type of user.

JSON response:

```
[{
  "id": 133,
  "account": {
    "accountNumber": "6335050000000111",
    "accountType": "TSys",
    "address": {
      "companyName": "",
      "street1": "",
      "street2": "",
      "street3": "",
      "street4": "",
      "country": "GB",
      "prepayBalance": 110
    }
  },
  "lastModifiedDate": "Apr 09, 2020",
  "lastModifiedBy": "uk@gmail.com"
}, {
  "id": 132,
  "account": {
    "accountNumber": "6335052400000034",
    "accountType": "PREPAY",
    "address": {
      "companyName": "",
      "street1": "",
      "street2": "",
      "street3": "",
      "street4": "",
      "country": "GB",
      "prepayBalance": 130
    },
    "bankAccount": {
      "id": 54390,
      "bankAccountName": "ABC Coompany",
      "bankAccountNumber": "3245",
      "sortCode": "12-34-56",
      "address": {
        "street1": "Fidelity Bank",
        "street2": "10 BANK STREET",
        "street3": "LONDON",
        "street4": "SW1A 2AA",
        "country": "GB"
      }
    }
  },
  "lastModifiedDate": "Apr 09, 2020",
  "lastModifiedBy": "ukcase@mailinator.com"
}]
```

As you can see in the response some may or may not receive `"bankAccount"` as response. I only need to select those which has bank account but at the same time count all the records.

Example:

```js
count(data.account.accountType) //somehow implement the count logic
count(data.account.bankAccount)

// Main logic
$scope.getAllDd = data.account.bankAccount; // get only those records with bankaccount in response
```

Which I can use for:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="ddAccounts in getAllDd">
  <td>{{ddAccounts.account.accountType}}</td>
```

Comment: Why would you stringify the data? Also, can't you filter where `data.account.bankAccount != null`?

Comment: Is it a bad practice. Its just a mock response thats why I thought to stringify. I am not using it in my actual code.

Comment: OK, I updated the question to remove the weirdness... lol

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes I am trying. Using this I can get records with bankAccount. But would it be helpful in getting total count of all ids with split of which has bankAccount and which has not. I understand it would be out of scope of this question but can comments on this will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the unfiltered accounts separate from the filtered ones.

```js
const app = angular.module('AccountApp', []);

const hasBankAccount = (account) => account.account.bankAccount != null;

app.filter('objectValues', () => {
  return (obj) => Object.values(obj).join(', ');
});

app.controller('AccountController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.filters = {
    search: ''
  };
  // Filter here initially...
  $scope.accounts = getJson();
  $scope.filteredData = $scope.accounts.filter(hasBankAccount);
  
  // Filter even more on search...
  $scope.doSearch = function() {
    let filterField = document.querySelector('#txt-filter');
    let filterText = filterField.value.trim().toLowerCase();
    $scope.filteredData = filterText.length === 0
      ? $scope.accounts.filter(hasBankAccount)
      : $scope.filteredData = $scope.accounts
        .filter(hasBankAccount)
        .filter(account => {
          return account.account.accountNumber.toLowerCase().includes(filterText);
        });
  };
});

function getJson() {
  return [{
    "id": 133,
    "account": {
      "accountNumber": "6335050000000111",
      "accountType": "TSys",
      "address": {
        "companyName": "",
        "street1": "",
        "street2": "",
        "street3": "",
        "street4": "",
        "country": "GB",
        "prepayBalance": 110
      }
    },
    "lastModifiedDate": "Apr 09, 2020",
    "lastModifiedBy": "uk@gmail.com"
  }, {
    "id": 132,
    "account": {
      "accountNumber": "6335052400000034",
      "accountType": "PREPAY",
      "address": {
        "companyName": "",
        "street1": "",
        "street2": "",
        "street3": "",
        "street4": "",
        "country": "GB",
        "prepayBalance": 130
      },
      "bankAccount": {
        "id": 54390,
        "bankAccountName": "ABC Company",
        "bankAccountNumber": "3245",
        "sortCode": "12-34-56",
        "address": {
          "street1": "Fidelity Bank",
          "street2": "10 BANK STREET",
          "street3": "LONDON",
          "street4": "SW1A 2AA",
          "country": "GB"
        }
      }
    },
    "lastModifiedDate": "Apr 09, 2020",
    "lastModifiedBy": "ukcase@mailinator.com"
  }];
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0.25em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

.toolbar {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.details {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="AccountApp">
  <div ng-controller="AccountController">
    <div class="toolbar">
      <input type="button" value="Filter" ng-model="query" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }" ng-click="doSearch()">
      <input type="text" id="txt-filter">
    </div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Acct. No.</th>
          <th>Acct. Type</th>
          <th>Address</th>
          <th>Bank Name</th>
          <th>Bank Acct. No.</th>
          <th>Bank Address</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="account in filteredData | orderBy : 'account.accountNumber' | filter : filters.search">
          <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ account.account.accountNumber }}</td>
          <td>{{ account.account.accountType }}</td>
          <td>{{ account.account.address.country }}</td>
          <td>{{ account.account.bankAccount.bankAccountName }}</td>
          <td>{{ account.account.bankAccount.bankAccountNumber }}</td>
          <td>{{ account.account.bankAccount.address | objectValues }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="details">
      <strong>No. of Accounts: </strong>
      <span ng-bind="filteredData.length"></span> /
      <span ng-bind="accounts.length"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: By now I have reached till the filtered stage by doing `filter:isActive` and defining a function in `isActive` in controller where I used your logic `data.account.bankAccount != null`

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with .filter() methods ? ... something like:

```
$scope.getAllDd = data.account.filter(xx=> xx. bankAccount)

this.totalRecords = data.account.length;
```

and then

```
<tr ng-repeat="ddAccounts in getAllDd">
  <td>{{ddAccounts.account.accountType}}</td>
```

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: Not tried map and filter . I am trying using them now.

Comment: Here lenght is obviously javascript function. Just wondering why doesn't the code won't consider length as key of json

Comment: Yes, it gives error for the data.account.length as `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: i said length cause i don't know if your back end expose a totalcount property (better) ..maybe you can use ? notation (if you use latest js features like data?.account.length || 0 ..something like this